# Why is the configuration generated with Arm's setup not persistent?

Tags: configuration, debian, nyx

I use Arm 1.4.5.0 with Tor 0.2.6.10 from the Tor repositories on a standard Debian Wheezy (7, oldstable) server.

When I first launch `arm` I am not sure whether `tor` is already running. No nickname is indicated in the Arm panel header. I configure my relay with the Arm Setup Wizard. Once the wizard completes, Arm outputs the message:

```
[ARM_NOTICE] Tor needs root permissions to start with this
 configuration (it will drop itself to the current user afterward). To
 continue...
 - open another terminal
 - run "sudo /home/myusername/arm/startTor"
 - press 'r' here to tell arm to reconnect
```

(by the way, typing `r` should be done in the Tor Configuration File panel and only once Tor has been stopped. In the main Arm page typing `r` just resizes the graphs.)

Once I have done as instructed, my relay nickname & exit policy are displayed in the Arm header, and it progressively picks up activity. Nevertheless, Arm shows this warning (which does not seem to have an effect):

```
[ARM_WARN] the torrc differs from what tor's using.
You can issue a sighup to reload the torrc values by pressing x.
```

My problem is this: **every time I reboot, I have to start all over again**! It seems that the `torrc` created/edited by Arm is not persistent. This is not just inconvenient: I am afraid that after a power outage, my relay will just boot back into a default exit relay configuration.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. The message you see is in fact a false alarm. [According](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/16459) to the `arm` maintainer:

> That message simply means that tor is currently running with the 'RunAsDaemon'
>   option enabled, but this setting isn't in your torrc. This message is
>   meant to help people who edit their torrc, forget to restart tor, and
>   are then confused why the settings didn't take effect.

A simple solution is to edit your `/etc/tor/torrc` file and then run `systemctl restart tor` (for `systemd`). You can also copy the contents of  `~/.arm/torrc` into `/etc/tor/torrc` and then start tor by `/arm/startTor`.

Comment: The message itself is not my problem… what I am concerned about is that every time I reboot, I have to re-configure Tor through Arm so that my relay runs with my configuration.

Comment: Simplest solution is to edit the `/etc/tor/torrc` file, restart `tor` and then launch `arm` and ignore the message.

Comment: I replaced `/etc/tor/torrc` with `~/.arm/torrc` (the file that resulted from Arm Setup Wizard), and now when I launch `arm`, I am immediately prompted by the Wizard again… my settings have somehow been lost. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ah! I had to start Tor again via the `/arm/startTor` script -- it was my understanding that Tor would start by itself at reboot (as a "deamon"), but it does not. So, replacing the contents of `/etc/tor/torrc` with those of `~/.arm/torrc` solves my problem. @Ron, can you edit your answer, or write a new one with this?

Comment: @doobadooba yes, as "...people who edit their torrc, *forget to restart tor, and are then confused why the settings didn't take effect*." ;) Edited by question. You may accept it as the answer if it helped you ;)

Comment: Indeed. Nevertheless, the core problem is that the Arm Wizard edits a `torrc` file which is _not persistent across reboots_ (regardless of whether one “forgets to restart tor“). Only the manual editing of `/etc/tor/torrc` solved it for me.